# How to set the profilepic in php

Tags: php, html

If profile picture set, that means I have to insert 1 in DB fiels, otherwise insert 0. But using the below code, it is inserting only 0 everytime.

```
$ssmid='SSM10';
isprofilepic--->tablename

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM useralbum WHERE isprofilepic="1" AND ssmid='$ssmid'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

//If there is already profile pic set then if block executes and set it to 0.
 if($count == '1'){
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
         $profileid = $row['id'];
     }
     $profile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='0' WHERE id='$profileid'");
     if($profile){
         echo "SUCCESS";
     }
     else{
         echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
     } 
 }  

//After setting previous pic 0, update new pic to 1. (This will works on both cases if already profile pic is set and there is first time setting profile pic )

$newprofile = mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='1' WHERE  ssmid='$ssmid'");
if($newprofile){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
}
```

Comment: try adding an "or die(mysql_error());" to the end of all sql lines.. You will get some error if there are errors in your queries

Comment: So we are still using the deprecated mysql functions. `isprofilepic--->tablename` heck?  And what errors/unexpected results are you getting? don't expect us to read the code, assume and shoot an answer.

Comment: i am not getting any error,it will inserting only 1 on id number 23,but what i did mistake i don't know

Comment: "SELECT id FROM useralbum WHERE isprofilepic="1" AND ssmid='$ssmid'"  - notice that you store 1 in "" (double quotation marks). Try to change it to ' (single quotation marks)